# Why does my code in a script element not run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I have the following script in my smarty template:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    $(document).ready(myBookings);
</script>
```

However it doesn't work on page load. `$(document).ready(myBookings);` does work when I run it in Mozilla firebug console though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have both `src` attribute and inner content in one `<script>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes

Answer (score 3):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block for your document-ready handler

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(myBookings);
</script>
```